# Visual Studios Compiling Querys

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I am busy building an application in C# and WPF, using an MVVMish design pattern. At the moment it consists of a dll and an exe.

My question is why when I try to compile the program it only successfully works when the platform is set to Mixed Platforms? For example if I change it to Any CPU it compiles and runs but doesn't pick up any new changes that I made in the dll, but when I set it to Mixed platform it picks up the changes.

Another thing is when I was working on the project initial, I could debug it in x86 mode, but when I tried to release it in x86 it says it couldn't find the assemblies, even the ones in the same exe file. I did notice that this only seemed to happen in wpf where in the windows or usercontrol tag where I had the xmlns:View...etc it couldn't find the view??

Just wondering :D

Comment: Please begin accepting answers on your other questions, so we don't get the impression that you don't really care whether we take the time to answer your questions.

Comment: A good answer can always get votes from other discerning viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If projects do not appear to be building even though you are making changes or projects do not get built even though you issue build all then follow these steps:

- Select the build configuration you are having trouble with
- Click "Build -> Configuration Manager"
- Ensure that there is a check mark in the "Build" column for every project in your solution

This problem is caused by Visual Studio's new habit of defaulting application projects to "x86" and library projects to "Any CPU".  The net result is that you immediately get a hodgepodge of configurations in you **solution**, *some of which are not selected to be built*.

Basically you have to sort or exactly which combination of which type of **project** platform to be built for your **solution** platform and make sure that all projects are **selected to be built**.

For example, this may require selecting that the "Any CPU" library is to included and built along with the "x86" application in the "x86" solution configuration.

Comment: Thanks man that makes sense, had a look and that seems to have been the problem :)